# Why does LabVIEW allow characters within Numeric control?

Tags: labview

Why does [LabVIEW](http://www.ni.com/labview/) allow characters (Key down) within Numeric control?

[image]

When I hit  <kbd>Enter</kbd> , it will clear all the characters and return to 0.

My question is: why does it allow only specific characters(not all)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is done for user convenience.

So to enter 5000 you can enter 5k, or to enter 0.000005 you can enter 5u.

LabVIEW allows you to enter text then validates it after you hit enter.

Also, there is an option to write text inside a numeric control for example:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Other usages are NaN, inf, E+8